# Azure function .net 7 upgrade issue: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, <...>'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

In my Azure function, I'm having issues after upgrading from.NET Core 3.1 to.NET Core 7.0.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

[image]

All of my nuget packages have been updated to the most recent version, but I still don't understand why this keeps happening.
What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried manually adding a reference to the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http) Nuget package?

Comment: In .NET 7, Functions only supports isolated mode. You need to change some of the libraries etc. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/announcing-the-net-7-for-azure-functions-isolated-worker-process/ba-p/3671398

Comment: @DavidG I did try, but no luck.

Comment: a) change to `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>` b) this is a complete sample project, try to mimic that https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples/Net7Worker

Comment: Did you set FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~4 in app settings which I believe is required for version over .Net Core

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). I see you already have a transciption for the error message, but not for the code or XML.

Comment: do not post images, instead give the text of your code. See SO guideline on [Why should I not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)?

Answer (score 3):

> In my Azure function, I'm having issues after upgrading from.NET Core 3.1 to.NET Core 7.0

**.NET 7.0 In-Process is not yet released for the Azure Functions as mentioned in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions) of Azure Functions - .NET Supported Versions**.

[image]

Also, in `.csproj` file, you have written the Target Framework as `Net7.0` to the `v3` Azure Functions Version which is incorrect.

[image]

**Azure Functions Core Tools Version 3 Supports only 3.1 in .NET and v4 supports .NET 6, 7 and Framework 4.8 as stated in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages)**.

Also, Microsoft recommends migrating the **.NET 3.1 v3** Azure Functions Project to the **.NET 6** In-Process for good workflow as you can see in below official screenshot:

[image]

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-version-3-version-4?tabs=net6-in-proc,azure-cli,windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp#choose-your-target-net) and Nicksnettravels [article](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/migrate-azure-function/) for more information on migration steps of .NET 3.1 to Higher Versions to make sure your code is compatible.

**Upgrade your function Code from .NET 3.1 to the supported Versions such as .NET 6 (In-process, Isolated Process) and .NET 7 Isolated process for the good compatibility code workflow**.